# To find the nearest smaller value based on a variable input inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to find all the files with format: `100_Result.out`, `101_Result.out`, ... `104_Result.out` from the subdirectories of a directory: `/as/test_dir/`. 
The structure of the subdirectories looks like: `/as/test_dir/4/`, `/as/test_dir/5/`,`/as/test_dir/6/`, `/as/test_dir/7/`, ...

So, if I have a variable `num=102` in the script, then I want to check all the `*_Result.out` files and need to capture the file which is one value smaller than the `num` variable
– i.e., I want the file: `101_Result.out`.
Similarly, if `num=101`, then file should be `100_Result.out`

But sometimes it could happen that the `.out` files are not in sequential,
i.e., not all values are present. 
So, if `num=102` but there is no `101_Result.out` file,
but I have a `100_Result.out` file in one of the sub-directories,
then that's what I want.

I tried below and I believe somehow I've reached to it
but it doesn't look perfect.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="/as/test_dir"
files=( $(find "$dir"/*/ -type f -name "*_Result.out" -exec basename "{}" \;) )
num=102

len=${#files[@]}
i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
    var=$(echo "${files[$i]}" | awk -F'_' '{print $1}')
    dif=$(($num - $var))
    if [[ "$dif" -ge '1' ]];then
        echo "$dif" >> tmpfile
    fi
    let i++
done

arr=( $(cat tmpfile) )
min=${arr[0]}
max=${arr[0]}
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    if [[ "$i" -lt "$min" ]];then
        min="$i"
    elif [[ "${#arr[@]}"  -eq '1' ]]  &&  [[ "${arr[0]}" -eq '1' ]];then
        min="$i"
        for j in "${files[@]}"
        do
            var=$(echo "${j}" | awk -F'_' '{print $1}')
            if [[ $(($num - $var)) -eq "$min" ]];
            then
                file_name="${var}_Result.out"
                echo "$file_name"
            fi
        done
    fi
done
echo "$min"
#rm tmpfile
```

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Why don't you just search for `101_Result.out` when `num=102` instead?

Comment: @oguzismail: sometimes it could happen that the `.out` files are not in sequential,i.e if `num=102`, then it may happen that i've only `100_Result.out` file in one the sub-directories....bit complex :(

Comment: So you want one smaller or any smaller? Your explanation is confusing. `and need to capture the file which is one value smaller than the num variable` is wrong? You wrote "one value smaller".

Comment: (1) This question would be clearer if you specified whether the filenames are always *NNN* \_Result.out (i.e., a three-digit number, between 100 and 999) or whether you can have `97_Result.out`, `2021_Result.out`, etc.  (2) If there are multiple files with the same number (i.e., a tie; e.g., `/as/test_dir/4/101_Result.out` and ``/as/test_dir/7/101_Result.out``), what do you want?  All of them?  One particular one?  One at random? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) It’s (almost?) never necessary to do `find "$dir"/*/ …`.  Just do `find "$dir" …`.  The `find` command will read the `$dir` directory and handle everything it discovers; no need to ***also*** use a glob.  (4) Try to use meaningful variable names.  `num`, `arr` and `var` are not meaningful.  (5) Why do you define a `max` variable and then never use it?  (6) Please indent your code correctly (so as to illuminate its structure).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and need to capture the file which is one value smaller than the num variable .... if i've num=102 in the script, then i want the file: 101_Result.out

Just glob the file.

```
echo "$dir"/*/"$((num - 1))_Result.out"
```

> sometimes it could happen that the .out files are not in sequential,i.e if num=102, then it may happen that i've only 100_Result.out file in one the sub-directories

Try not to store state in bash. Instead, write one long big pipeline. Like ex. so:

```
# Get all files
find "$dir"/*/ -type f -name "*_Result.out" |
# Extract the number in first column separated by space.
sed 's~.*/\([0-9]*\)_Result.out$~\1 &~' |
# Filter only smaller
awk -v num="$num" '$1 < num' |
# Get first file smaller file
sort -n | tail -n1 |
# Remove the number
cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Comment: finally!!it's working, maybe i didn't understand with your reference: `not to store state in bash` ? thanks :-)

Comment: `files=(` <- you store state in an bash array Then you store state in `min=` and `max=` and in loop iterators. Prefer not to use any bash at all.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not specify what to do if there are multiple files
with the same number (i.e., a tie;
e.g., `/as/test_dir/4/101_Result.out` 
and `/as/test_dir/7/101_Result.out`). 
This answer assumes that you want all of them.

### One Step

This is very similar to [Darkman’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67888043/1672723#67890824), but

- It handles pathnames somewhat better.
- IMO, it’s clearer. 
  It uses meaningful variable names (one-letter names are too short),
  looser spacing (169 characters is too many for a one-liner),
  and a simpler algorithm (no subtraction).

```
dir="/as/test_dir"
num=102
find "$dir" -type f -name '*_Result.out' |
          awk -F'[/_]' -v limit="$num" '
                                {
                                  this_num = $(NF-1)
                                  if (this_num < limit)
                                     {
                                        numbers[$0] = this_num
                                        if (this_num > max) max = this_num
                                     }
                                }
                        END     { for (i in numbers) if (numbers[i] == max) print i }
                '
```

- You clearly already understand the `find` command —
  find all files in and under `$dir` whose names match `*_Result.out`.
- Pipe into `awk`.  
  Each filename (pathname) becomes an input record to `awk`.
- `-F'[/_]'` means use slash (`/`) and underscore (`_`) as field separators. 
  That means that a filename (input record) of `/as/test_dir/4/100_Result.out`
  gets broken into these fields:

      `$1`
      = (blank)
      `$2`
      =
      `as`
      `$3`
      =
      `test`
      `$4`
      =
      `dir`
      `$5`
      =
      `4`
      `$6`
      =
      `100`
      `$7`
      =
      `Result.out`

  (`$1` would be set to the text before the first `/`  (or `_`) 
  if there were any.)
- As illustrated above, the number part of the file name
  is the second-to-last field in the record; i.e., `$(NF-1)`. 
  This depends on the fact that the file name
  always contains exactly one underscore, and it comes right after the number. 
  (See Part 2 of this answer for a more flexible approach.)
- If the number is less than the limit (e.g., 102),
  save the pathname in an array, associated with the number.
- If the number is less than the limit
  but more than the maximum we have seen so far, update the maximum. 
  (We don’t need to initialize `max` explicitly;
  `awk` automatically initializes all variables to zero<sup>1</sup>.)
- Finally, print all the pathnames that are associated with the max value.

The above will list (all) the desired filenames on the standard output. 
As you know, you can put them into an array
by putting `arr=(` before the `find … | awk …` pipeline, and `)` after it.

________
<sup>1</sup> Actually, variables are initialized to null. 
This is treated as zero when it is used in a numeric context.

---

### Two Steps

The above is OK
for producing a human-readable, displayable list of filenames. 
However, filenames *can* contain weird characters
like space, tab, newline, `*`, `?`, etc.;
[processing the output from `find` can be problematic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/23408). 
A somewhat safer approach is to determine the `max` value,
and then, as a second step, `find` the file(s) that match that value. 
You can then process those files with `-exec`.

```
max=$(find "$dir" -type f -name '*_Result.out' |
          awk -F'/' -v limit="$limit" '
                                {
                                  this_num = $NF
                                  sub(/_Result.out/, "", this_num)
                                  if (this_num < limit)
                                     {
                                        numbers[$0] = this_num
                                        if (this_num > max) max = this_num
                                     }
                                }
                        END     { print max }
                '
        )
if [ "$max" = "" ]
then
        echo "No file(s) found."
else
        find "$dir" -type f -name "${max}_Result.out"
fi
```

- `-F'/'` means use only slash (`/`) as field separator. 
  That means that a filename (input record) of `/as/test_dir/4/100_Result.out` gets broken into these fields:

      `$1`
      = (blank)
      `$2`
      =
      `as`
      `$3`
      =
      `test_dir`
      `$4`
      =
      `4`
      `$5`
      =
      `100_Result.out`
- Here, the last (rightmost) component of the pathname (i.e., the file name)
  is the last field in the record; i.e., `$NF`. 
  This, of course,
  is equivalent to the `-exec basename "{}"` you’re already using.
- Temporarily assign the file name to the `this_num` variable. 
  Then strip off the `_Result.out` part (by `sub`stituting null for it),
  leaving just the number. 
  Strictly speaking, the `sub` call should be

```
sub(/_Result\.out/, "", this_num)
```

to treat the **`.`** as a literal dot
rather than an any-character (wildcard). 
But we know that the fourth-to-last character in the file name
is an actual dot, because it matched the `-name`.

At the end, just print the maximum number,
capturing the value in a shell variable, …

…, and then find the files that match that number (name).

Comment: By the way, I developed this answer before KamilCuk posted their answer.  I typed it at about the same time as when KamilCuk posted their answer.  I then spent the next 40 hours (off and on) battling with Stack Overflow’s buggy post validation engine, which was rendering false ‘’not properly formatted’’ errors.